# Autoload module class in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've created a module that has an override for the `FrontControllerCore` class to add additional Smarty variables.

The issue I'm running into is trying to autoload a class that is referenced in the controller that is in my module. The class isn't being loaded and I don't know how to add it to the autoloader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install the module the FrontController.php file should be located in:
override\classes\controller\

so from the FrontController.php you can "include" manually that file like:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../modules/servicecharges/classes/ServiceCharge.php');
```

There's no autoload for such includes.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use this free tiny module that override Prestashop autoload. After that all your module custom class will be autoloaded.

**Exemple path:** `/modules/my_module/libs/classes/MyClass.php`

[Extended Api](http://prestasupertool.com/en/accueil/1-pst-api.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to solve a similar problem, with Composer's autoload. [Way to require an autoload in one file on a Prestashop module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939448/way-to-require-an-autoload-in-one-file-on-a-prestashop-module/38631944#38631944)

Instead of overriding a controller (leading to conflicts with other plugins or installations of Prestashop already using the same overrides) you could invoke the hook **moduleRoutes**.

This way, you could call your autlooader always before the controllers:

```
<?php

public function hookModuleRoutes() {
  require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; // And the autoload here to make our Composer classes available everywhere!
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).