# How to add a class to PrestaShop autoload

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to figure out the best way to load a class into PrestaShop that I can use on overriding controllers.

I started off by creating a module that has an override of the Controller class with my files required at the top. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Isn't it the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110821/autoload-module-class-in-prestashop ?
"PrestashopDeveloper" answered that "There's no autoload for such includes.", therefore you have to put your file in override at install, and call it accordingly.

Comment: Puth minus do not look to the code. I'd like this) first

Comment: Solved a related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939448/way-to-require-an-autoload-in-one-file-on-a-prestashop-module/38631944#38631944

Answer (score -3):

If you do not want to put class to override folder you can change class_index.php

Who add minus it is his problem but I'm right. If you do not want to use override folder you can set module folder with class

```
'SomeClass' => 
    array (
      'path' => 'modules/yourmodulename/class/class_name.php',
```

It is not normal but you can override without using override folder in particular circumstance.

And if you will read with carfull you will see: If you do not want to put class to override folder

**EDITED 2015/10/19**

It is craizy to add minus for what you do not know.

1) First look to PrestaShopAutoload class

2) all your class paths in array in the public $index in PrestaShopAutoload

3) what you need to do? just change this array

4) how to change this array? in your module you can get this instance using this PrestaShopAutoload::getInstance()

5) after you got instance you have full controll of your class paths!!! and you can add eny path what you need

6) what we need now? just make our module work maximum befour other class used. How we can do? Just hook in dispacher.

Comment: AFAIK, the class_index file is generated; and therefore it's not a good idea to manually overwrite it, you'll lose your changes as soon as PS will regenrate it !

Comment: As I was say "If you do not want to put class to override folder". And you could controll using actionDispatcher hook. It is not standart way, but it can work and for some case more useful

Comment: Pierre-Olivier Vares >"AFAIK, the class_index file is generated; and therefore it's not a good idea to manually overwrite" Who sayed monually? You can add your module in actionDispatcher and change, and then just controll for class path exist.