# Way to require an autoload in one file on a Prestashop module?

Tags: php, composer-php, prestashop, autoload

I'm trying to use a set of libraries with Composer for a Prestashop module.

My current approach is to include the `vendor/autoload.php` file on every file (`mymodule.php`, `controllers/front/foo.php`, `controllers/admin/bar.php`, etc.)

Doing the require only on top of the `mymodule.php` is not a solution, I don't see any hook to do the task.

Is there a better approach than copy & paste the same snippet on top of every PHP file? Thank you!

Comment: Wait for the newer version of Prestashop then.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of PrestaShop you are using, but there is a **actionDispatcher** hook in the dispatcher, maybe you could use to it do your custom loading, before the controller is executed. https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/Dispatcher.php#L353

Comment: Wooow, that's a good one... I should start to investigate it

Comment: The work now would be on including in a hook the autoload in a global context...

Comment: Aaarggh! Almost working!!!. I would need a hook before `$controller = Controller::getController($controller_class);`

Comment: I've did it! See my accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the way to do it!

The **actionDispatcher** hook was working for me with models, hooks, but not with controllers.

Seems like there is a not documented hook called **moduleRoutes** which loads **before** any controller.

So I've been able to autoload in all my module's classes this way:

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

//_PS_MODULE_DIR_

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; // Autoload here for the module definition

class MyCustomModule extends Devnix\Prestablocks\Module { // My custom Prestashop framework (in experimental phase, https://github.com/devnix/prestablocks)

  // ...

  public function install() {
    return
      parent::install() &&
      $this->registerHook('moduleRoutes'); // Register the hook
  }


  public function hookModuleRoutes() {
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; // And the autoload here to make our Composer classes available everywhere!
  }
```